# True or false: if $R,S\subseteq A\times A$ then $\operatorname{dom}(R\cap S)=\operatorname{dom}(R)\cap\operatorname{dom}(S)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, relations

$\newcommand{R}{\mathcal{R}}\newcommand{S}{\mathcal{S}}\newcommand{dom}{\operatorname{dom}}$

> Let $\R,\S\colon A\to A$ i.e. $\R,\S\subseteq A\times A$. Prove or disprove: $$\dom(R\cap S)=\dom(R)\cap\dom(S).$$ Note. If $\mathcal{M}\subseteq A\times B$ then $\dom(\mathcal{M})$ is defined as the set $\{x\in A\mid\exists y\in B\wedge(x,y)\in \mathcal{M}\}$.

---

True. Proof:

$\subseteq)$ Let $x\in\dom(\R\cap\S)$. Then by definition of domain, there exists an $y\in A$ such that $(x,y)\in\R\cap\S$. By definition of intersection, it means $(x,y)\in\R$ and $(x,y)\in\S$. Again by definition of domain, we have $x\in\dom(\R)$ and $x\in\dom(\S)$, and by definition of intersection, we end up with $x\in\dom(\R)\cap\dom(\S)$.

$\supseteq)$ Let $x\in\dom(\R)\cap\dom(\S)$. By definition of intersection, $x\in\dom(\R)$ and $x\in\dom(\S)$. By definition of relation, there exists an $y\in A$ such that $(x,y)\in\R$ and $(x,y)\in\S$. By definition of intersection, $(x,y)\in\R\cap\S$, so by definition of domain, we end up with $x\in\dom(\R\cap\S)$.

**Is it correct?**

Thanks!!

Comment: x being in dom(R) and dom(S) means that there exists a y1, and y2 such that (x,y1) belongs to R, (x,y2) belongs to S.

Comment: @DavidPeterson thanks! Yes, I had doubts on that implication... So $x\in\operatorname{dom}(\mathcal{R})$ and $x\in\operatorname{dom}(\mathcal{S})$ means that there exists $y_1,y_2\in A$ such that $(x,y_1)\in\mathcal{R}$ and $(x,y_2)\in\mathcal{S}$. But now I can't apply intersection because it can be $y_1\neq y_2$. What does follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\{1,2,3\}, R=\{(1,2),(2,2)\}, S=\{(1,3),(2,2)\}$

$$\text{dom}(R\cap S) = \text{dom}\{(2,2)\} = \{2\}$$
$$\text{dom}(R)\cap \text{dom}(S) = \{1,2\}\cap\{1,2\} = \{1,2\}$$